# Lookup primary ID from multiple tables having another (unique) field

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm trying to add values in a junction table of a many to many relationship.

Tables look like these (all IDs are integers):

**Table A**

```
+------+----------+
| id_A | ext_id_A |
+------+----------+
|   1  |    100   |
|   2  |    101   |
|   3  |    102   |
+------+----------+
```

**Table B** is conceptually similar

```
+------+----------+
| id_B | ext_id_B |
+------+----------+
|   1  |    200   |
|   2  |    201   |
|   3  |    202   |
+------+----------+
```

Tables PK are id_A and id_B, as columns in my junction table are FK to those columns, but I have to insert values having only external ids (ext_id_A, ext_id_B).

External IDs are unique columns, (and therefore in a 1:1 with table id itself), so having ext_id I can lookup the exact row and get the id need to insert into junction table.

This is an example of what I've done so far, but doesn't look like an optimized sql statement:

```
-- Example table I receive with test values
declare @temp as table (
    ext_id_a int not null,
    ext_id_b int not null
);

insert into @temp values (100, 200), (101, 200), (101, 201);

--Insertion - code from my sp
declare @final as table (
    id_a int not null,
    id_b int not null
);

insert into @final
select a.id_a, b.id_b
from @temp as t
inner join table_a a on a.ext_id_a = t.ext_id_a  
inner join table_b b on b.ext_id_b = t.ext_id_b

merge into junction_table as jt
using @final as f
on f.id_a = jt.id_a and f.id_b = tj.id_b
when not matched by target then
insert (id_a, id_b) values (id_a, id_b);
```

I was thinking about a MERGE statement since my stored procedure receives data in a Table Value Parameters parameter and I also have to check for already existing references.

Is anything I can do to improve insertion of these values?

Comment: this is why they teach you about normalization in school

Comment: Yeah, I know.. I didn't create these tables but I have to find my way out anyway

Comment: So what is the problem with your approach?

Comment: I'm not an expert of sql server/tsql, so I was just asking if there is a better approach to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the `@final` table variable:

```
; with cte as (
     select tA.id_A, tB.id_B 
     from @temp t 
     join table_A tA on t.ext_id_a = tA.ext_id_A 
     join table_B tB on t.ext_id_B = tB.ext_id_B
)
merge into junction_table
using cte
on cte.id_A = junction_table.id_A and cte.id_B = junction_table.id_B
when not matched by target then
insert (id_A, id_B) values (cte.id_A, cte.id_B);
```

Comment: I will accept your answer since no one else answered and it seems a good advice. I didn't know the difference between temp table and cte - so I thank you anyway

Comment: Yes, CTE is an important concept, it comes quite handy at times; take a look at recursive CTE's as well, they are very powerful. As for my answer, I hope this is what you wanted to achieve... Take care!